# Get data after submit form in database using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page of post message of all users.

[image]

It is possible to submit form and get it automatic in database? because i did not use input type for date and i leave current timestamp as a default in database.

[image]

form with show post message

```
<form  id="formsubmitcomment">
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id?>">
  <textarea name="post" id="post" style="resize: none" placeholder="What's  on your mind">
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
</form>

<?php
  require './database.php';
     $showpostcomment = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
     $sql = "SELECT user_id, post_comment from postcomment ORDER BY postcomment_id DESC";
     mysqli_stmt_prepare($showpostcomment, $sql);

      mysqli_stmt_execute($showpostcomment);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($showpostcomment, $user_id, $post_comment);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($showpostcomment);

      while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($showpostcomment)) 
     {
?>
        <div class="w3-panel w3-white" id="postcomment">
           <p id="comment"><?php echo $post_comment ?></p>  
        </div>
<?php 
    } 
 ?>
```

After I submit post it will also appear with other post message of other users by getting the id = postcomment in the div element

jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function (){
    var post = $("#post").val();

    $.post("postcomment.php", $("#formsubmitcomment").serialize(), function(){
      $("#postcomment").load("showpostcomment.php", function(data){
      $("#comment").prepend(data + "br");
      $("#post").val("");                    
              });
          });         
   });
 });
```

I insert the post message in postcomment.php and then load it in showpostcomment.php with the same code as below form with user_id

showpostcomment.php

```
 require './database.php';
       $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
      $showpostcomment = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  $sql = "SELECT user_id, post_comment from postcomment WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY postcomment_id DESC";
      mysqli_stmt_prepare($showpostcomment, $sql);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($showpostcomment, "i", $user_id);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($showpostcomment);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($showpostcomment, $user_id, $post_comment);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($showpostcomment);

      echo $post_comment;
     mysqli_stmt_fetch($showpostcomment);

        echo "$post_comment";   

     ?>
```

Comment: how do i get the submit data and line up with other message of other user?

Comment: Can you please show your code in showpostcomment.php ?

Comment: i edit sir in showpostcomment

Comment: i did not use while loop but it still get all post message of user instead of one

Comment: I have post an answer, Please check if it works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query in your showcomment.php

```
SELECT user_id, post_comment from postcomment WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY postcomment_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This way you will only get the last inserted record.

Change below code.

```
    <form  id="formsubmitcomment">
      <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id?>">
      <textarea name="post" id="post" style="resize: none" placeholder="What's  on your mind">
      </textarea>
      <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
    </form>

        <?php
          require './database.php';
             $showpostcomment = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
             $sql = "SELECT user_id, post_comment from postcomment ORDER BY postcomment_id DESC";
             mysqli_stmt_prepare($showpostcomment, $sql);

              mysqli_stmt_execute($showpostcomment);
              mysqli_stmt_bind_result($showpostcomment, $user_id, $post_comment);
              mysqli_stmt_store_result($showpostcomment);
        ?>
             <div class="w3-panel w3-white" id="postcomment">
          <?php
              while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($showpostcomment)) 
             {
        ?>

                   <p class="comment"><?php echo $post_comment ?></p>  

        <?php 
            } 
         ?>
         </div>
```

Also this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function (){
    var post = $("#post").val();

    $.post("postcomment.php", $("#formsubmitcomment").serialize(), function(){
      $("#postcomment").load("showpostcomment.php", function(data){
      $("#postcomment").prepend("<p class='comment'>"+ data + "</p>");
      $("#post").val("");                    
              });
          });         
   });
 });
```

Comment: it will show all message of the user in horizontal sir

Comment: do it need to move another div because it is in while loop the id=postcomment?

Comment: You can not give same IDs to multiple divs. Ids must be unique. Create only one div outside of while loop. Inside your loop just put P tag with class comment and in your js code prepend the outer div #postcomment with new p tag. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: it will erase all message sir

Comment: including other users post comment and 1st post comment submit